# When i factory reset my phone, does it restore my phone data and my mobile data?

Tags: samsung, insufficient-memory

My phone is running out of space, and even when I delete someone my things, it is still low space

Comment: You will find some first-aid and useful links in our [insufficient-memory tag-wiki](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/insufficient-memory/info).

Answer (score 1):

No, it will clear out the whole phone memory including contacts and other data but not the SD Card data. Before doing the factory reset, first save your data from phone memory and then go with the Format Factory procedure of your phone.

Here are some best tips to make space and increase memory:

1.) Move all downloaded apps to SD storage.

2.) Remove all unwanted apps and data.

3.) Clear out the cache from the phone. For this just go to settings>>apps and select app and you will get the clear cache option. (You have to do it for all applications installed in phone memory.)

Comment: Using the term *SD card* doesn't make it clear whether you're talking about external or internal or both of SD cards. Please be specific with that.